# Excel VBA update inventory value to another sheet error

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Sheets in my excel, "Sheet1" is for making receipt and "Sheet2" is for the inventory stock. what I want to do is when user insert product name into row A16 and A17, the item quantity from "Sheet2" with the same name is updated. 
The code that I make can update quantity item from cell A16 but the quantity item of cell A17 isn't updated(shown in the image). anybody know whats wrong with my code ? In the Image there is 2 item, cheese Cheetos and hot Cheetos. when I make my receipt only cheese Cheetos quantity is decrease 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Mwa.png)

Here is the code

```
Sub printInvoice()
Dim rng1, rng2, cell1, cell2 As Range
Dim rConstants As Range
Dim lastRow1 As Long
lastRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A16:A17" & lastRow1)

Dim lastRow2 As Long
lastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & lastRow2)

Dim lr4 As Long
lr4 = Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each cell1 In rng1
    If IsEmpty(cell1.Value) Then Exit For
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            If IsEmpty(cell2.Value) Then Exit For
                If cell1 = cell2 Then

                        cell2.Offset(0, 2) = cell2.Offset(0, 2) - cell1.Offset(0, 1)
                        Sheet1.PrintOut
                        Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("A" & lr4).Value = Sheet1.Range("B11")
                        Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("B" & lr4).Value = Sheet1.Range("B10")
                        Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("C" & lr4).Value = Sheet1.Range("A16")
                        Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("D" & lr4).Value = Sheet1.Range("C16")
                        Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("F" & lr4).Value = Sheet1.Range("D19")
                        Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("G" & lr4).Value = Sheet1.Range("D18")
                        Sheets("DaftarPenjualan").Range("H" & lr4).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 5)
                        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Value + 1
                        Set rConstants = Sheet1.Range("A16:C" & "C17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                        rConstants.ClearContents

                    End If
                End If
        Next cell2
Next cell1

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey justin, I need to know something here, columns and rows where your data starts on sheet 2. Which columns are for the product name and it's stock?

Comment: @Damian the data starts from rows 2. the product name is in column B and the quantity is on column D

Comment: Ok, give me some minutes and i'll write you another way to do this.

Comment: Ok, hope that you can help me

Comment: there you go Justin, try my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, im assuming you have no duplicate items on your inventory, or else it would crash when storing  the items on the dictionary

```
Option Explicit
Sub printInvoice()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsInventory As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastRowInventory As Long, i As Long
    Dim DictInventory As Scripting.Dictionary 'You need to check Microsoft Scripting Runtime on your references for this to work
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Substract As Integer
    Dim arrInventory 'here we will store your inventory

    With ThisWorkbook 'with this you are referencing both sheets on this workbook so its shorter to call them
        Set ws = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsInventory = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    Set DictInventory = New Scripting.Dictionary
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'this is to know how many items are sold

    With wsInventory
        LastRowInventory = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'this is to get all your inventory
        arrInventory = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LastRowInventory, 4)).Value 'storing your inventory
    End With

    For i = 2 To UBound(arrInventory) 'here we loop through your inventory to know in which row is every item and store the row
        If Not arrInventory(i, 1) = vbNullString Then DictInventory.Add arrInventory(i, 1), arrInventory(i, 3)
    Next i

    With ws
        For Each C In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow) 'we are looping through the first sheet to substract the inventory
            Substract = .Cells(C.Row, 3)
            arrInventory(DictInventory(C.Value), 3) = arrInventory(DictInventory(C.Value), 3) - Substract
        Next C
    End With

    'Paste the values modified to the sheet
    wsInventory.Range(wsInventory.Cells(1, 2), wsInventory.Cells(LastRowInventory, 4)).Value = arrInventory

End Sub
```

Edit:
I don't know if you already thought of this but to avoid problems I would use a data validation list on the reciept sheet to pick up the product which is fed by the inventory sheet. That way there will be no problems not finding some products for typos.

Comment: hey I tried it and it gives me an error saying 'User Defined type not defined.

Comment: I think you didn't read the comments, but you should Check the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` before running this code. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: hey @Damian I just try it again and already check the scripting runtime, but it shows an error again saying 'This key is already associated with an element of this collection'. When I debug this line shows error 'DictInventory.Add arrInventory(i, 1), arrInventory(i, 3)'. can you help me ?

Comment: This means you got duplicates on your inventory... check the value of `arrInventory(i, 3)` it is duplicated.

Comment: but i've check the product name and it doesn't have any duplicate. what is the value stored in arrInventory(I, 3) ?? the quantity ??.. sorry im still new to coding stuff

Comment: My bad, you have to check arrIventory(i, 1) as you well said the 3 is for the quantity, the item on arrIventory(i, 1) is the item you have duplicated. It can't be a blank cell because the code checks for blank cells before doing anything.

Comment: ok now it says subscript out of range. this line is the problem when debug 'arrInventory(DictInventory(C.Value), 3) = arrInventory(DictInventory(C.Value), 3) - Substract'. do you know why ?